# HBase bulk delete using MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, scalability

Using a mapreduce job I am trying to delete rows from a Hbase table.

I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.
```

It looks like this is caused by the output set to KeyValue by configureIncrementalLoad. It only has PutSortReducer and KeyValueSortReducer but not a DeleteSortReducer.

My Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class DeleteRows extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class Map extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Delete> {

        ImmutableBytesWritable hKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable();
        Delete delRow;

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            hKey.set(value.getBytes());
            delRow = new Delete(hKey.get());
            context.write(hKey, delRow);
            // Update counters
            context.getCounter("RowsDeleted", "Success").increment(1);
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(conf);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Delete stuff!");
        job.setJarByClass(DeleteRows.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Delete.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

        HTable hTable = new HTable(args[2]);
        // Auto configure partitioner and reducer
        HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return (0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new DeleteRows(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Is there a better / faster way to delete a large number of rows using their row keys? Obviously deleting each row in a mapper is possible however I would imagine that is slower than bulk pushing deletes to the correct region server.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal is to generate HFile with `Delete` stream (actually deleting marks as `KeyValue`) inside. And standard way to do so is to use `HFileOutputFormat`. Actually you can only place stream of `KeyValue` changes into this format and there is 2 standard reducers: `PutSortReducer` and `KeyValueSortReducer`. Setting number of reduce tasks to 0 you actually pass all `Delete` directly to output format which of course cannot work.

Your most obvious options:

- Add your reducer `DeleteSortReducer`. Such reducers are pretty simple and you can just almost copy. You need only to extract individual KeyValue stream from Delete and sort them. `PutSortReducer` is good example for you. `Put` changes are not sorted so this is why such reducer is needed.
- Just construct not stream of `Delete` but stream of appropriate `KeyValue` containing delete marks. This is maybe best thing for speed.

Comment: Roman, what do you mean by creating an appropriate `KeyValue` containing delete marks? Maintain my own field that determines if the row is deleted or not, and then at regular interval clean up all rows that need to be deleted?

Comment: No, Delete in HBase is actually mark rather than operation: http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2011/12/deletion-in-hbase.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out by using `TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob` to setup the reducer instead of `HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad` the code works fine.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(tableName, null, job);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

However, this still does not create deletes for the completebulkload utility. It simply executes the delete RPC.